# B&K 4006s in field recording..

Tags: microphone, field-recording

Hi,
I'm currently building my field recording/wildlife rig. I have a matched pair of B&K4006s and wonder if anyone has experience of using these in the field. Should I hold on to them or sell them and replace with something else?
My current arsenal includes:

Sennheiser 416 and ME66 with K-6.
Telinga parabola with stereo dat mic.
Matched pair of AKG 414s.
Microtech Gefell UMT70S.
Rode Classic.

Any advice would be gratefully received!
Thanks
Phil.

Comment: I think you are pretty well covered. I have done some atmos recording with the 4006, and I like the sound very much.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question here and there was a good link to a Nagra article involving the B&Ks: [LINK](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/13247/bk-4006s-for-field-recording)

I used a pair for some nature recording recently, through a Sound Devices 442. There was wonderful clarity to them when I did some general forest ambience gathering. Really captured the tone of birdsong well.

I found using them in exceptionally quiet areas would uncover their self noise a bit though. But a minor trade off.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would hang on to the 4006s as they are excellent mics and ideally suited for atmos recording.

Comment: Cheers Iain. Im going to hang on to them!

Comment: @iain, I bought rycote lyremounts and softie kits for them. Mounted them on a straight bar and had a wee listen to my ever bustling rhododendron bush! Really nice atmos.. and a surprising amount of detail too! They are now officially in the kit.!

Answer (score 0):

I would try them with a jecklin disc. I bet you would get some nice results with ambiences and that setup.

Comment: I have to go do a wee bit of research.. I never heard of a Jecklin disk until this very minute!!


Comment: It is a fun technique to try with omnis: 
http://www.xix-acoustics.com/studiy/2008/05/20/diy-a-jecklin-disk-for-stereo-recording-with-omnis/